# How do you spawn specific monsters in Minecraft SMP?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you spawn specific monsters in Minecraft SMP?  I have the vanilla server.

Comment: You could try giving yourself 52:# but I believe it will only spawn pigs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The vanilla server only offers basic commands to administrate the server, give items and change the time of day.

You will need to use a [bukkit plugin](http://bukkit.org/)

Answer (score 1):

in the current weekly snapshot, there are items in creative called "spawn eggs" that you can use to spawn animals. there is no vanilla way to spawn mobs in 1.0 though.